# Generating MM7 Soap Request in Java

Tags: java, xml, mms, smil, mm7

I need to generate a MM7 Soap message just like following one. i could generate the MM7 Soap but the SMIL Message part and the Image/Text attachments are problems.
Does anyone know how to generate that parts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<P:Envelope xmlns:P="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<P:Header>
<mm7:TransactionID   xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-0" P:mustUnderstand="1" >1343706064118205</mm7:TransactionID>
</P:Header>
<P:Body>
<mm7:SubmitReq xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-0">
<mm7:MM7Version>6.3.0</mm7:MM7Version>
<mm7:SenderIdentification>
<mm7:VASPID>1000</mm7:VASPID>
<mm7:VASID>0005</mm7:VASID>
<mm7:SenderAddress>
<mm7:Number>Dialog MMS</mm7:Number>
</mm7:SenderAddress>
</mm7:SenderIdentification>
<mm7:Recipients>
<mm7:Bcc>
<mm7:Number>94773087654/TYPE=PLMN</mm7:Number>
</mm7:Bcc>
</mm7:Recipients>
<mm7:ServiceCode>105</mm7:ServiceCode>
<mm7:DeliveryReport>true</mm7:DeliveryReport>
<mm7:Subject>DailyMirror News Service</mm7:Subject>
<mm7:ChargedParty>Neither</mm7:ChargedParty>
<mm7:ChargedPartyID></mm7:ChargedPartyID>
</mm7:SubmitReq></P:Body></P:Envelope>
```

--==========fBS6FtL4PDKimRjInCAaIDytdJ9ulmContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-Type: multipart/related; type="application/smil"; start=""; boundary=481bf3d684924bbee13179cd4576eda8--481bf3d684924bbee13179cd4576eda8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-ID: <35_1>Content-Type: text/plain; name="35_1.txt"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="35_1.txt"1.ABC
2. XYZ
--481bf3d684924bbee13179cd4576eda8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-ID: <35_2>Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="35_2.jpg"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="35_2.jpg"......Exif..II*.................Ducky.......<......Adobe.d................................

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitContent-ID: Content-Type: application/smil; name="mms.smill"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mms.smill"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/SMIL20/CR/Language">
<head>
<layout>
  <root-layout width="300" height="300" background-color="white"/>
  <region id="Item0" top="125" left="1" width="99%" height="49%" fit="fill"/>
</layout>
</head>
<body>
<par dur="10s">
  <text region="Item0" src="cid:35_1"/>
  <img region="Item1" src="cid:35_2"/>
</par>

</body>
</smil>
```

Answer (score 2):

the final request should like like this one, take care of mime boundaries part

```
--mime-boundary-boundary1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-ID: <mm7_msg>

<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
1348056868070-1-
</mm7:TransactionID>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<SubmitReq xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2">
<MM7Version>5.3.0</MM7Version>
<SenderIdentification>
<VASPID>Ejada</VASPID>
<VASID>Ejada</VASID>
</SenderIdentification>
<Recipients>
<To>
<Number>1111</Number>
</To>
</Recipients>
<DeliveryReport>true</DeliveryReport>
<Subject>Allah Akbar</Subject>
<Content href="cid:mms_cid" />
</SubmitReq>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

--mime-boundary-boundary1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="mime-boundary-boundary2"
Content-ID: <mms_cid1>

--mime-boundary-boundary2
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-ID: <contentId1.txt>
Content-location: contentlocation1.txt

test from jmeter, hello world!

--mime-boundary-boundary2
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-location: Ejada.jpg

(=================binary data for the image goes here)

--mime-boundary-boundary2
Content-Type: application/smil
Content-ID: <smil file>
Content-location: smil file

<smil>
    <head>
        <layout>
            <root-layout height="80" width="101"/>
            <region fit="hidden" height="50%" id="Text" left="0%" top="0%" width="100%"/>
            <region fit="hidden" height="50%" id="Image" left="0%" top="50%" width="100%"/>
        </layout>
    </head>
    <body>
      <par dur="5000ms">
        <img region="Image" src="Ejada.jpg"/>
        <text region="Text" src="sample.txt"/>
      </par>
    </body>
</smil>

----mime-boundary-boundary1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using InstantCom's MM7 java library https://github.com/vnesek/instantcom-mm7 (shameless disclosure, I'm maintainer) you can generate more or less identical request with:

```
    SubmitReq sr = new SubmitReq();
    sr.setNamespace("http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2");
    sr.setMm7Version("5.3.0");
    sr.setVaspId("Ejada");
    sr.setVasId("Ejada");
    sr.setSubject("Allah Akbar");
    sr.setDeliveryReport(true);
    sr.addRecipient(new Address("1111", RecipientType.TO));
    sr.setTransactionId("1348056868070-1-");

    // Attach a SMIL presentation
    BinaryContent smil = new BinaryContent("application/smil", load("smil-sample2.xml"));
    smil.setContentId("smil");

    // Attach a picture
    BinaryContent image = new BinaryContent("image/jpeg", load("lorena.jpg"));
    image.setContentId("image");

    // Attach a text
    TextContent text = new TextContent("Lorena sends a lots of hugs!");
    text.setContentId("text");

    // Pack it all up
    sr.setContent(new BasicContent(smil, image, text));

    MM7Message.save(sr, System.out, new MM7Context());
```

Output would be:

```
--==MM7-SOAP==5474f579-afe1-4b23-b8e2-0b162f89fd94
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-ID: <mm7-soap>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2" env:mustUnderstand="1">1348056868070-1-</mm7:TransactionID>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <mm7:SubmitReq xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2">
      <mm7:MM7Version>5.3.0</mm7:MM7Version>
      <mm7:SenderIdentification>
        <mm7:VASPID>Ejada</mm7:VASPID>
        <mm7:VASID>Ejada</mm7:VASID>
      </mm7:SenderIdentification>
      <mm7:Recipients>
        <mm7:To>
          <mm7:Number>1111</mm7:Number>
        </mm7:To>
      </mm7:Recipients>
      <mm7:MessageClass>INFORMATIONAL</mm7:MessageClass>
      <mm7:DeliveryReport>true</mm7:DeliveryReport>
      <mm7:Subject>Allah Akbar</mm7:Subject>
      <mm7:Content href="cid:mm7-content" />
    </mm7:SubmitReq>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
--==MM7-SOAP==5474f579-afe1-4b23-b8e2-0b162f89fd94
Content-Type: multipart/related; start="<smil>"; type="application/smil"; boundary="==Multipart==7f92313b-8941-4e9e-8ea6-a0838d80e63b"
Content-ID: <mm7-content>

--==Multipart==7f92313b-8941-4e9e-8ea6-a0838d80e63b
Content-Type: application/smil
Content-ID: <smil>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<smil>
    <head>
        <layout>
            <root-layout height="80" width="101"/>
            <region fit="hidden" height="50%" id="Text" left="0%" top="0%" width="100%"/>
            <region fit="hidden" height="50%" id="Image" left="0%" top="50%" width="100%"/>
        </layout>
    </head>
    <body>
      <par dur="5000ms">
        <img region="Image" src="cid:image"/>
        <text region="Text" src="cid:text"/>
      </par>
    </body>
</smil>
--==Multipart==7f92313b-8941-4e9e-8ea6-a0838d80e63b
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-ID: <image>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<skipped binary content>
--==Multipart==7f92313b-8941-4e9e-8ea6-a0838d80e63b--
--==MM7-SOAP==5474f579-afe1-4b23-b8e2-0b162f89fd94--
```